# MS-Office Document Conversion to .PDF Format

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I am looking for a MS-Office document to .PDF 3rd party software that does not create the need for my code to manipulate the COM directly. I am looking for a package that is native to .net. I have already looked at the following:

http://www.cete.com/

http://www.pdfonline.com

Are there any other SDK packages that you are aware of that can meet my needs?

If the software package manipulates the COM on it's own, that is fine. I just don't want to perform any operations against the COM within my code. I would also prefer it to be C# based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ASPOSE.NET Total](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx) & [TXTextControl](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnet/overview/) .NET.

Comment: Thanks. This has the basics for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might find one here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sertf2pdf.aspx ; and perhaps here as well: www.novapdf.com/kb/convert-word-to-pdf-microsoft-office-word-documents-to-pdf-208.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PDF Conversion Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx). It provides everything in a modern and convenient Web Services based SDK. All self contained, no need for IIS.

C# sample code [can be found here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check on the win32ole for converting the microsoft document into PDF

Check the saveas command on the document object of the Win32ole.
You can save an MS office doc(doc/xls/PPT) as PDf